# No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[SolutionName.Areas.Identity.Data.SolutionNameUser]' has been registered

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

When i added the EmailSender for password recovery and email confirmation using [microsofts guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/accconfirm?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio) I got this message on startup. I've tripple checked if i've done everything in the guide correctly and I have (from what i can see) and the app worked as it should before i added everything from the guide. I've done this before on another app and didnt have any problems with it, so i feel that i'm stuck now.

I'm using Razor Pages.

My ConfigureServices in Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
    {
        // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
        options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
        options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
    });

    services.AddAuthentication()
        .AddFacebook(facebookOptions =>
    {
        facebookOptions.AppId = Configuration["Authentication:Facebook:AppId"];
        facebookOptions.AppSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Facebook:AppSecret"];
    })
    .AddGoogle(googleOptions =>
    {
        googleOptions.ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientId"];
        googleOptions.ClientSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientSecret"];
    });
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
    services.AddSingleton<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
    services.Configure<AuthMessageSenderOptions>(Configuration);
}
```

Comment: Ah can it be that i'm missing 'services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()' ?. Yeah i just followed the guide and that's how they did it.

Comment: When i added that i got 'InvalidOperationException: Scheme already exists: Identity.Application'